# Can an Azure Service Bus communicate with the Mailchimp API?

Tags: azureservicebus, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My organization is sending messages to an azure service bus.  If the message is of a certain type, I would like create a call to the Mailchimp API. Is this possible and is this a good design idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add reliability, this is definitely the pattern to follow. Some process that requires email notification to be sent creates a message with the intent. The message is retrieved by a service responsible to send out emails and it handles this intent. If logic execution fails, the intent is not lost as the messages are durable. With Azure Service Bus, if messages continuously fail, they will be [dead-lettered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues) and handled separately.

> If the message is of a certain type, I would like create a call to the Mailchimp API.

Depending on how you implement your logic, you will need to decide wherever the same process handles messages with the intent to send an email or if it should be a separate process with its own dedicated queue. Personally, I would suggest having a separate queue handling messages with email intent. That way this process can have a different SLA than the process handling other business messages.